# Mongoose finding subdoc by id method returns undefined

Tags: mongoose

I have a Client model that has an income subdoc array:

```
const incomeSchema = new Schema({
    source: String,
    amount: Number,
    recurring: Boolean,
    recurRate: String,
})

...

const clientSchema = new Schema({
...
income: {type: [incomeSchema], default: []},
```

I've used mongoose's method to find subdocs ([https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html][1]) successfully before if I structure the query like:

```
Client.findById(clientId)
.then((client)=> {
client.income.id(incomeId)
...
})
```

I was refactoring to try and make a reusable component on the frontend and trying to pass less params for that to work. The following should work, and does find the parent object, but the income array comes back undefined:

```
Client.find({"income._id": incomeId})
.then((client) => {
//console.log(client) -- shows correct parent document is found with income array of subdoc objects
//console.log(client.income) -- shows undefined

client.income.id(incomeId)
...
})
```

this doesn't result and gives the error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Now if I change the model.find() to model.findOne() the second syntax structure works. I'm just curious if anyone knows why the document found by find() and findOne()comes back in some different form that mongoose is not recognizing the child schema arrays, even though both find the same parent document. Just trying to better understand how mongoose operates under the hood.

In case anyone comes across this question and needs a working code example:

```
ParentModel.findOne({"child._id": childId})
.then((parent) => {
parent.childarray.id(childId)
//do stuff
res.send(result)
})

  [1]: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html
```

Comment: find returns an array since it is made to return multiple results for a given query? so client[0].income?

Comment: @cmgchess Ohh ya, thas right. Went and tested it out to be sure.

Comment: nice you can write an answer if u want